# How to stop a subscription after the response to a service/store has a certain argument/value

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, ngrx

I have, say a service, or a store selector, to be more accurate, that returns an object that changes after some time (returns a different object).

But the thing is, I want to unsubscribe from this service after this object has a certain property in it, or (later) if a property has a certain value to it.

I know i'ts usual to use the takeUntil function from 'rxjs', i've used pipe(first()) before when i just needed to get the first response from a service, or .pipe(takeuntil(destroy$)) when the component using it is destroyed ( I manipulate destroy$ )

I want to stop subscribing to a service/observable after the response I get from it has a certain property in it, or if that property has a value I deem final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`takeWhile`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takewhile.html) is a good option here. For example:

```
observable$.pipe(
    takeWhile(x => x.someProperty !== someValue))
```

Just be sure to negate the condition, as I've done above, so that values are taken *while* the property doesn't have the value you want. This means it will stop (and unsubscribe) once the value matches.

To get the actual value that caused `takeWhile` to end the subscription, pass `true` as a second parameter to `takeWhile` (`inclusive`):

```
observable$.pipe(
    takeWhile(x => x.someProperty !== someValue, true))
```

> When the optional `inclusive` parameter is set to `true` it will also emit the first item that didn't pass the predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Just unsubscribe

```
subscription // as field eg


subscription=yourObservable.subscribe(()=> if whaever subscription.cancel()); //or .unsubscribe() cant remember now
```

or use `takeUntil` operator

```
observable.pipe(takeUntil(val=> some test ).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: I've tried this too, I get an error saying I can't access the variable before initilization or something like that

Comment: Thats why make it a field - or `takeUntil`